# Are questions about IDE misbehaviours on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Due to a mixed set of reasons, I often use an archaic version of a presumably common development environment in my home projects; namely Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. Lately, it has been displaying a strange behaviour, not in anything related to its function (building applications) but rather in its form (in the way the program handles its own windows).

If there were no Stack Overflow, I would try to file a bug in the manufacturer's records and hope for assistance regarding a decade-old software, but I've grown used to ask my questions to other developers in Stack Overflow, where you typically get much faster and useful responses.

However this time my question is not related to any specific programming language or skill but about a possible bug, so to speak, in either the IDE software or the IDE user (i.e. me). Is Stack Overflow an appropriate platform to place such kind of questions?

Comment: Does the problem persist in a fresh project? It's not likely that software just changes behavior from one day to the next, something had to change. I would point a finger at an OS update, but you don't mention the problem happening in other pieces of software. So perhaps some project/workspace files got corrupted which is caused the IDE to behave wonky. <--- see the epic unfounded guesswork, it is exactly why these kind of questions don't really work on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: In case it matters for the mixed set of reasons: There is a free-as-in-beer "community edition" of VS.Studio. So if the mixed set of reasons was really money... :-)

Comment: There is [tag:visual-studio-2008] tag specifically for this reason and it's perfectly [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as it's about *"software tools commonly used by programmers and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"*. Make sure to present problem clearly and it a way others will be able to find it and use the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Overflow really isn't meant as a substitute as accurate and valid bug reports for software...so I would recommend that you look into filing a bug report with the creators of Visual Studio and get this addressed.

If you were to ask a question about your current setup today, you *might* be asked why you're forced to use such an old version of VS, and whether or not you can upgrade.  If you ask this kind of question, you should be prepared to get the answer, "This is fixed in a newer version, you should upgrade."  If you aren't, official support channels are your best bet.

Comment: Oh, and ask Nick if you should upgrade... I think he's on a fence.

Comment: Note that "report with the creators of Visual Studio" for 2008 will get you absolutely nothing unless it is "for security fixes" - https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs-servicing-vs.

Comment: Instead of *preparing* for answer "this is fixed in newer version" one can explain reasons why he has to stick to older version. Always do. One sentence and it makes a big difference for people.